# error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence on appharbor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

i got the following error when uploaded my files to `AppHarbor`

```
    [HttpCompileException]: d:\temp\f3fkwz4z.mbc\temp\root\0c956e8e\9304c5fb\App_Web_ixu4pbnj.0.cs(43): error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.CompileAssemblyBuilder(AssemblyBuilder builder)
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.<CompileNonDependentBuildProviders>b__0(AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder)
   at System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.CompileParallel(ICollection assemblyBuilders, Action`1 action)
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.CompileNonDependentBuildProviders(ICollection buildProviders)
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler.Process()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileWebDirectoriesRecursive(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileWebDirectoriesRecursive(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileWebDirectoriesRecursive(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean topLevel)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileAppInternal(VirtualPath startingVirtualDir, IEnumerable`1 excludedVirtualPaths)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(VirtualPath startingVirtualDir, IEnumerable`1 excludedVirtualPaths)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback, IEnumerable`1 excludedVirtualPaths)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback, List`1 excludedVirtualPaths)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManagerHost.PrecompileApp(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback, List`1 excludedVirtualPaths)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback, Boolean forceCleanBuild)
   at System.Web.Compilation.ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication(ClientBuildManagerCallback callback)
   at System.Web.Compilation.Precompiler.Main(String[] args)
```

although no such file exist in my project it is `Asp.Net MVC4` project with `EntityFramework`
i dont understand from where the error comes

Comment: Do you have your own App_Web.cs file?

Comment: The error appears to come from a view file based on the location of the error.  Try setting your MvcBuildViews to true locally, then build and see if VS can give you a more precise location of the error. Specifically, you are probably looking for a stray or misplaced or missing \  http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx

Comment: @jim no i dont have such named file in my project

Comment: @tommy bro that error comes from appharbor Project works fine in VS

Comment: AppHarbor appears to be compiling your views.  That weird named file is what you see when MSBuild compiles the views.  That is why I recommended setting that locally to see if you can find where it is complaining.

Comment: every time i build the project on apparbor it shows error in other file than previou

Comment: I think you are saying the file name changes each time your push to AppHarbor?  That would be the expected behavior, those are dynamically generated "file names".  I have seen malformed HTML cause these same errors.

Comment: @Tommy thanks bro by making MvcBuildViews  to true my problem is now solved

Comment: No problem - glad you got it figured out!  Posted as an answer so people with the issue in the future won't have to parse our comments to discover a potential solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That strange file name that you are seeing is AppHarbor compiling your cshtml/vbhtml files when you deploy.  Any errors in those files (bad Model property calls, even bad HTML) can cause the build to fail on those files and provide some pretty cryptic errors.

Try setting the MvcBuildViews property to true ([Here is how to do that via Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx)) and see if you can use Visual Studio to help localize and correct the error.